# How do I create horizontal or vertical struts and glue for use with scala BoxPanel?

Tags: swing, scala

In Java, the class java.swing.Box contains methods to create horizontal and vertical struts and glue. Struts and glue is usefull to space elements when using BoxLayout.

```
Box.createHorizontalStrut(10)
Box.createVerticalStrut(10)

Box.createHorizontalGlue()
Box.createVerticalGlue()
```

Where can I find the corresponding methods in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the methods in the scala Swing companion object:

```
import swing.Swing

Swing.HStrut(10)
Swing.VStrut(10)

Swing.HGlue
Swing.VGlue
```

Comment: I found very handy to import all members of the Swing object (ie. `import scala.swing.Swing._`) in my swing related classes